# How to cancel NSURLSession from another class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I have a MySession class that I call in order to obtain the URL of a website's redirect.  In my `ViewController` I'd like to cancel the session when the user navigates back out of the `ViewController` via `ViewDidDisappear`.   I know that `NSURLSessionTasks` have a `.cancel` method, but I can't think of the best way to do this.  I could store the current task in a Singleton but thought there must be a better way?

```
class MySession: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate {


    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: NSHTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest!) -> Void) {



    }



    // fetch data from URL with NSURLSession
    class func getDataFromServerWithSuccess(myURL: String, noRedirect: Bool, callback: Result<String> -> Void) {

        var loadDataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask? = nil
        let sessionConfig: NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

        //MARK: Toggle timeout on tests
        sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60.0
        sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60.0



        var myDelegate: MySession? = nil
        if noRedirect {
            myDelegate = MySession()
        }

        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: myDelegate, delegateQueue: nil)
        loadDataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: myURL)!) { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in


                if let checkedData = data {

                let success = Result.Success(NSString(data: checkedData, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding) as! String)


                callback(success)

                } else {

                    let error = NetworkError.FailedUrl("\(myURL) + \(error)")


                    if let request = loadDataTask?.currentRequest {

                        guard let urlExtension = request.URL?.pathExtension else {return}
                        guard let domain = request.URL?.host else {return}



                            guard let finalURLAsString = request.URL?.description else {return}
                            let failure = Result.Failure("\(finalURLAsString) + \(error)") 
                            callback(failure)

                        }

                    }

                }
        }
        loadDataTask!.resume()


    }


class MyViewController:  UIViewController {

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
       //TODO:  How to stop MySession task?




               MySession.getRedirectionInfo(urlAsString)

                MySession.getDataFromServerWithSuccess(urlAsString, noRedirect: false) { result in

            //omitted for brevity 
        }
```

Comment: From my point of view it is possible to delegate this by Delegate pattern.

Comment: Can you elaborate at all on how to do that?  I've tried but when I set a delegate, i.e. `weak var delegate = TaskCancelAble?` I get "instance member delegate cannot be set on type MySession"

Answer (score 0):

Another option to get a reference to the task is to use the method
[- getTasksWithCompletionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/getTasksWithCompletionHandler:) from `NSURLSession`, that lists all tasks on the session combined to the property [taskDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTask_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionTask/taskDescription) on `NSURLSessionTask` to identify the tasks

Comment: Great point, but I still need to access this property from my other class which is where I'm having difficulty

Comment: My bad, I thought the defaulConfiguration had the same behavior as the backgroundConfiguration, where you can recreate the session as long as you use the same id.